# Order of regular expression operator (..|.. ... ..|..)

Tags: c#, regex

What is the order of priority of expressions in `(..|. .. .|..)` operator - left to right, right to left or something else?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Left to right, and the first alternative matched "wins", others are not checked for. This is a typical NFA regex behavior. A good description of that behavior is provided at [regular-expressions.info ***Alternation*** page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

Note that `RegexOptions.RightToLeft` only makes the regex engine examine the input string from right to left, the modifier does not impact how the regex engine processes the pattern itself.

Let me illustrate: if you have a `(aaa|bb|a)` regex and try to find a match in `bbac` using `Regex.Match`, the value you will obtain is `bb` because `a` alternative appears after `bbb`. If you use `Regex.Matches`, you will get all matches, and both `bb` and `a` will land in your results.

Also, the fact that the regex pattern is examined from left to right makes it clear that *inside a non-anchored alternative group, the order of alternatives matter*. If you use a `(a|aa|aaa)` regex to match against `abbccaa`, the first `a` alternative will be matching each `a` in the string (see the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(a%7Caa%7Caaa)&i=abbccaa)). Once you add word boundaries, you can place the alternatives in any order (see [one more regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb(a%7Caa%7Caaa)%5Cb&i=abbccaa%20aa%20a%20aaa)).

Comment: I think there are regex engines which always take the longest match, instead of the first here.

Comment: POSIX-compliant regex engines require the longest match. Also, Perl6 `/ pattern1 | pattern2 /` also matches the longest alternative (there is a `||` operator that works as a simple `|` in most other flavors to yield the first found alternative).

Comment: In Python 3.8.2 (CPython) it seems to be left to right too, not the longest one. Example: `re.sub(r"3rd (col|column)", '_', '3rd column')` returns `'_umn'`