# Why does the position of my Regex pattern effect the matching?

Tags: regex

Hi I am using a regex checker regex101.com to verify that my regex pattern is working. What I dont understand is why the position of my pattern

```
\/checkout\/index.jsp\?announceEmpty.*
```

does not work when it is at the end of my pattern match.

This regex DOES NOT work

```
\/checkout\/index.jsp.skipReprice=true|\/checkout\/index.jsp|\/checkout\/index.jsp\?announceEmpty.*
```

vs. this DOES work

```
\/checkout\/index.jsp.skipReprice=true|\/checkout\/index.jsp\?announceEmpty.*|\/checkout\/index.jsp
```

and these are the texts to match against

```
/checkout/index.jsp?skipReprice=true
/checkout/index.jsp
/checkout/index.jsp?announceEmpty=1&lastItemRemoved=Gola%20x%20
```

Comment: thank you @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: You are welcome, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35606463/3832970) should be helpful.

Comment: Note that the regex you says works matches `/checkout/index.jsp?skipReprice=true my dog has fleas`. I don't know if that is intended. Depending on requirements and the regex engine you use, you may want to add an end-of-line anchor `$` or end-of-string anchor `\z` at the end. If you did so it would no longer match the string I mentioned.

Comment: Rather than "or-ing" regexes that all start at the beginning of the string, you want to work left-to-right, only use alternation when needed, often within a non-capture group (`(?:...|....|....)`). For example, `/\/checkout\/index\.jsp\??(?:skipReprice=true|announceEmpty=.*%\d+)?$/`. See [PCRE engine Demo](https://regex101.com/r/I8UbEf/1/).