# How do I replace each substring in a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby

I have a string:

```
story = 'A long foo ago, in a foo bar baz, baz away...foobar'
```

I also have matches from this string (the dictionary is dynamic, it doesn't depend on me)

```
string_matches = ['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foobar'] # words can be repeated
```

How to replace each match with `**foo**`? to get a result:

```
story = 'A long **foo** ago, in a **foo** **bar** **baz**, **baz** away...**foobar**'
```

for example my code:

```
string_matches.each do |word|
  story.gsub!(/#{word}/, "**#{word}**")
end
```

returned:

```
"A long ****foo**** ago, in a ****foo**** **bar** ****baz****, ****baz**** away...****foo******bar**"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to check if the words are matched as whole words, you may use

```
story.gsub(/\b(?:#{Regexp.union(string_matches.uniq.sort { |a,b| b.length <=> a.length }).source})\b/, '**\0**')
```

If the whole word check is not necessary use

```
story.gsub(Regexp.union(string_matches.uniq.sort { |a,b| b.length <=> a.length }), '**\0**')
```

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/krhCXT)

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:#{Regexp.union(string_matches.uniq.sort { |a,b| b.length <=> a.length }).source})` - this creates a pattern like `(?:foobar|foo|bar|baz)` that matches a single word from the deduplicated list of keywords, and sorts them by length in the descending order. See [Order of regular expression operator (..|.. ... ..|..)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35606426/order-of-regular-expression-operator) why this is necessary.
- `\b` - a word boundary

The `\0` in the replacement pattern is the replacement backreference referring to the whole match.

Comment: The interpolation on the 2nd one is superfluous. You can just use `story.gsub(Regexp.union(...), '**\0**')`

Comment: I would also use `.sort_by(&:length).reverse` instead of `.sort { |a, b| b.length <=> a.length }`. Which is in my opinion more clean and expressive. It is just personal preference and I'd understand if you leave the answer as is.

Answer (score 0):

A slight change will nearly get you there:

```
irb(main):001:0> string_matches.uniq.each { |word| story.gsub!(/#{word}/, "**#{word}**") }
=> ["foo", "bar", "baz", "foobar"]
irb(main):002:0> story
=> "A long **foo** ago, in a **foo** **bar** **baz**, **baz** away...**foo****bar**"
```

The trouble with the final part of the resulting string is that `foobar` has been matched by both `foo` and `foobar`.