# Match German company titles with Python regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match German company titles with Python regex.
Here is what I have:

```
(\bUnternehmergesellschaft\b|\bUG haftungsbeschränkt\b|\bUG (haftungsbeschränkt)\b|\bUG\b|\bUnternehmergesellschaft und Compagnie Kommanditgesellschaft\b|\bUG & Co. KG\b)
```

As you can see in the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/W2pZi5/4), I do not have a perfect match for each title. Especially when in comes to `.` or `(` and `)` it doesn't work.

Comment: 1) Escape special chars like `(` and `)`, etc. 2) Make sure you understand what `\b` matches in regex. `a\)\b` will only match in a string like `a)b` and not in `a);`.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I close a bracket in regex? https://regex101.com/r/7PqFq8/1 I tryied different versions...

Comment: `\bUG \(haftungsbeschränkt\)`. If you are adding word boundaries dynamically, please [read the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45145800/3832970).

Comment: I think I still have a fundamental problem in understanding. In order to solve my problem above, I need to understand, why this( https://regex101.com/r/7PqFq8/2) doesn't work

Comment: See [Order of regular expression operator (..|.. … ..|..)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35606426/order-of-regular-expression-operator), and [it will work](https://regex101.com/r/g5bO26/1).