# How to build a simple tokenizer

Tags: python, substring, tokenize

I would like to know how to build a very simple tokenizer. Given a dictionary d (in this case a list) and a sentence s I would like to return all possible tokens (=words) of the sentence. Here is what I tried:

```
l = ["the","snow","ball","snowball","is","cold"]
sentence = "thesnowballisverycold"

def subs(string, ret=['']):
    if len(string) == 0:
        return ret
    head, tail = string[0], string[1:]
    ret = ret + list(map(lambda x: x+head, ret))
    return subs(tail, ret)
    
print((list(set(subs(sentence))&set(l))))
```

But this returns:

```
["snow","ball","cold","is","snowball","the"]
```

I could compare substrings but there must be a better way to do this, right?
What I want:

```
["the","snowball","is","cold"]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can utilize a regular expression here:

```py
import re
l = ["the","snow","ball","snowball","is","cold"]
pattern = "|".join(sorted(l, key=len, reverse=True))
sentence = "thesnowballisverycold"
print( re.findall(pattern, sentence) )
# => ['the', 'snowball', 'is', 'cold']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ciJIMO).

The pattern will look like `snowball|snow|ball|cold|the|is`, see the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/llnEH5/1/). The trick is to make sure all alternatives are listed from the longest to shortest. See [Order of regular expression operator (..|.. ... ..|..)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35606426/order-of-regular-expression-operator). The `sorted(l, key=len, reverse=True)` part sorts the items in `l` by length in the descending order, and `"|".join(...)` creates the alternation pattern.

Comment: Why do you need to sort?

Comment: @SayandipDutta Otherwise,shorter tokens with the same prefix will get matched, like `snow` instead of `snowball`.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Right. +1