# Regex match from array of strings in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string

I am facing a bit problem in `Regex`. I want to find the start and end index of the complete matched string in the input string.

e.g. I have an array of strings like

```
["a", "aa"]
```

and I have a text like `I like a problem aa`

I am doing with iteration of array strings.

```
let arr = ["a", "aa"];
let str = "I like a problem aa";
let indicesArr = [];
arr.forEach(a=>{
  const regexObj = new RegExp(a, "gi");
  let match;
  while ((match = regexObj.exec(str))) {
    let obj = { start: match.index, end: regexObj.lastIndex }
    indicesArr.push(obj);
    if(!match.index || !regexObj.lastIndex) break;
  }
});
```

above code gives me the result

```
[
  {start: 7, end: 8},
  {start: 17, end: 18},
  {start: 18, end: 19},
  {start: 17, end: 19}
]
```

I want the result should be

```
[
  {start: 7, end: 8},
  {start: 17, end: 19}
]
```

Any suggestion would be very helpful, thanks:)

Comment: Use word boundaries to match a whole word, not a partial match.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for the suggestion,but if my string is `I like a problem aa and aaaa`, actually it's not matching the last `aaaa` part.

Comment: Then you need to use a `aa|a` regex.

Comment: I am not getting, can you please write a small example, it would be helpful thanks:)

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/wiktor_stribizew/jomL13rq/

Comment: Thank you, you are a geinus.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236009/discussion-between-abinas-patra-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `a` finds two matches in `aa`. You need to make sure you match all occurrences of a regex that finds either `aa` or `a` *in this order*. It means, the regex must be `/aa|a/g` and not `/a|aa/g` as the [order of alternation matters in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35606426/order-of-regular-expression-operator).

Here, you can use

```js
let arr = ["a", "aa"];
let str = "I like a problem aa";
let indicesArr = [];
arr.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);
const regexObj = new RegExp(arr.map(x=> x.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')).join('|'), "gi");
let match;
while (match = regexObj.exec(str)) {
    let obj = { start: match.index, end: regexObj.lastIndex }
    indicesArr.push(obj);
}
console.log(indicesArr);
```

Note these two lines:

- `arr.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);` - sorts the `arr` items by length in the descending order (to put `aa` before `a`)
- `const regexObj = new RegExp(arr.map(x=> x.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')).join('|'), "gi");` - escapes all items in the `arr` array for use inside a regex, and joins the items with `|` alternation operator into a single string regex pattern.